# Why the formula given to a cyclic R-module C changes to Ra, when R has identity and C is unitary.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

How can I prove that  the formula given to a cyclic R-module C changes to Ra, when R has identity and C is unitary, could anyone help me please?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $Ra$ is contained in $C$, so it suffices to show $C\subset R$ if $R$ has unity and if $C$ is unitary. But now 
$$
ra+na=ra+(a+a+\dots+a);
$$
can you go from here? By definition of $Ra$, you only need to show that the above element is of the form $sa$, for some $s\in R$.

Comment: " If $R$ has identity" means that $R$ has additive identity?

Comment: $s = (r +1 +1 + ...... +1)$  right?

Comment: I understand that $C$ is unitary so that $1a = a$, but why $R$ must have an additive identity? could u explain this for me please?

Comment: @Idonotknow rings *always* have an additive identity, as they are an additive group. The identity in question is multiplicative.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! your answer is so clear